# Use tap to click instead of click to select user on start up

Tags: macos, mac

I have Mac OS X 10.10.3. On startup of the OS you can select between different users on the machine. To select a user you have to do a full click, but instead I want to use tap to click.

Can this be changed in the settings somehow?

Comment: What do you mean by touch?

Comment: tap-to-click should be the correct translation I think.

Comment: I've been wondering about this for a while. Question upvoted.

Comment: Is your display a touch screen? Or do you wanna hover over the user without click? Or just 1 click?

Comment: @emotality: I'm using a Mac Book Pro without touch screen. I want to tap on the user instead of physically pressing down the trackpad.

Comment: No, I only tried `sudo defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Clicking -int 1`. I'll try yours and tell you the results.

Comment: @klanomath: It didn't worked. Even after a restart it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Is your "Tap to click" enabled?

[image: Tap to click]

Comment: Yes this is enabled, but still I have to do a "click" on login. Everything else seems to work with a tap, but not the login one.

Comment: That's a first! Have wired mouse plugged in, never noticed. Will edit answer once I get the answer! My bad..